# Efficiently group query by one column, taking the maximum of another column and a third column that comes from the same row as the maximum column

Tags: sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table of 100,000,000+ values, so efficiency is very important to me. I need to take information from table A, join it to an index table B, then join to table C using the index retrieved from table B. The problem is, there are multiple indexes for each value in table A, and I want to retrieve the one with the most recent date.

The query below creates duplicates:

```
SELECT ID_1, ID_2, Date
INTO #DEST_TABLE FROM Table_1 t1
INNER JOIN Table_2 t2 ON t1.ID_1=t2.ID_1
INNER JOIN Table_3 t3 ON t2.ID_2=t3.ID_2
```

This one does not, but when running with more than 35,000 vs 40,000 elements, the execution time goes from <5sec to >1min:

```
SELECT ID_1, ID_2, Date
INTO #DEST_TABLE FROM 
(SELECT * FROM Table_1 l CROSS APPLY Table_2 t2 WHERE t1.ID_1=t2.ID_1) t_temp
LEFT JOIN Table_3 t3 ON t_temp.ID_2=t3.ID_2
```

How can I decrease my execution time as much as possible?
Here is an example table:
[image]

For this table, I would be trying to get the most recent location for each person.
None of the columns are indexed and I cannot create indexes on this table.

Comment: Could you provide couple of things: 1> Not sure I am understanding the problem clearly as what you are asking does not resemble with the query you are trying to write. Could you provide the sample input and expected output data? 2> Could you share the DDL of the tables including the indexes they already have, 3> An execution plan if possible. These information would help someone provide you an accurate suggestion, rather than a generic best practice suggestion.

Comment: No one expects actual data. Sample data is what expected. Providing that, you have potential to receive a quicker and in some cases much better and efficient solution.

Comment: that makes sense. I have created an example table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First of all, when you are working on 100 Million+ records and that
   too joining to other tables, first thing I would ask is what is the
   rationale behind not creating indexes which can cover your query. If
   you are not the admin of that system, I would suggest that you
   should bring this up to admin group and try to understand what is
   the exact reason (if any) they do not want index on that huge table.
   Specially because you mentioned "**efficiency is very important to
   me**". 
   Remember that 'SQL Tuning' is only one of the steps of 'Database Performance Tuning' and you can tune only as much with writing a good SQL Query. When the data volume gets huge, a good SQL Query is never sufficient without taking other Performance Tuning Measures.
2. Apart from what Roger has already provided, here are a few solutions that you can try out:

**Solution 1**

```
SELECT  T1.ID_1, OA.ID_2, OA.Location
FROM    Table1 T1
        OUTER APPLY (
                        SELECT  TOP 1 T3.ID_2, T3.Location
                        FROM    Table2 T2
                                INNER JOIN Table3 T3
                                    ON T2.ID_2 = T3.ID_2
                        WHERE   T2.ID_1 = T1.ID_1
                        ORDER   BY T3.Date DESC
                    ) OA;
```

**Solution 2:**

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
        T1.ID_1
        ,T2.ID_2
        ,Location = FIRST_VALUE(T3.Location) OVER (PARTITION BY T1.ID_1 ORDER BY T3.Date DESC)
FROM    Table1 T1
        INNER JOIN Table2 T2
            ON T1.ID_1 = T2.ID_1
        INNER JOIN Table3 T3
            ON T2.ID_2 = T3.ID_2;
```

**Data Preparation:**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Table1

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Table2

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Table3

SELECT  TOP 10000 ID_1 = object_id, name
INTO    Table1
FROM    sys.all_objects 
ORDER   BY object_id

SELECT  ID_1 = T1.ID_1, ID_2 = IDENTITY(INT, 1, 1)
INTO    Table2
FROM    Table1 T1
        CROSS JOIN Table1 T2

SELECT  ID_2, Location = 'City_'+ CAST(ID_2 AS VARCHAR(100)), Date = CAST(DATEADD(DAY, ID_2/10000, GETDATE()) AS DATE)
INTO    Table3
FROM    Table2
```

**Indexes to cover the Solution 1:**

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_TABLE1_ID_1 ON Table1 (ID_1)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_TABLE2_ID_2 ON Table2 (ID_1, ID_2)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_TABLE3_ID_2 ON Table3 (ID_2, Date DESC) INCLUDE (Location)
```

**Execution Plan:**
[image]

You can see that all are 'Index Seek' except for Table1 which is an legitimate 'Index Scan' because you are doing scans for each value of Table1's ID_1 value. If you put a where clause in the outer loop to search for a few specific ID_1 values, then that 'Index Scan' will turn to a 'Index Seek' as well.

I will leave the Index Strategy for the 2nd solution to you (as a homework :) ). Tips: You have to make the Location as a key as well. Or you can go with COLUMNSTORE index approach.

Comment: I just contacted the dev's and now have table index access. Should I just create indexes on the ID columns? Will an index work if there are multiple duplicate ID's per column?

Comment: Updating the solution with index suggestion (now that you have confirmed in the comment you can create index in the system):

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
select top (1) with ties
    a.A_Id, b.B_Id, b.Date
from dbo.TableA a
    inner join dbo.TableB b on a.A_Id = it.A_Id
    inner join dbo.TableC c on c.B_Id = b.B_Id
order by row_number() over(partition by a.A_Id order by b.Date desc);
```

Alternatively, you can try an olde fashioneth approache:

```
select a.A_Id, b.B_Id, b.Date
from dbo.TableA a
  inner join dbo.TableB b on a.A_Id = b.A_Id
  inner join dbo.TableC c on c.B_Id = b.B_Id
where not exists (
  select 0 from dbo.TableB pb where pb.B_Id = b.B_Id and pb.Date > b.Date
);
```

However, as with all such situations, its performance will heavily depend on indices. SSMS can suggest you some, if you will look at the execution plan; off the top of my head, you will need all `Id` columns to be indexed, and you will need either a single `(Date)` or a composite `(A_Id, Date, B_Id)` on the `TableB`.

**UPD**: If you can't create or modify any indices, and performance is paramount, I would suggest copying the data in question into a separate schema or database, where you might have appropriate permissions. Apart from that... it's impossible to get something out of nothing.

Comment: I cannot create indexes on the table. I think it is because of this that my query is faster than yours. That being said, neither runs at a satisfactory speed.

Comment: @AndrewBorders, updated the answer with an alternative solution.